# let inside cond

Tags: lisp, clojure

I'm working with clojure and while I've dabbled with lisps before, I'm having trouble finding a clean way to nest let statements in cond statements. For example, consider the following function:

```
(defn operate-on-list [xs]
  (let [[unpack vector] (first xs)]
    (cond
      [(empty? xs) 'empty
       unpack vector
       :else (operate-on-list (rest xs))])))
```

It's a pretty standard recursive operation on a list, but it needs to do some work on the first element in the list before it works with the contents. The issue, of course, is that the list may be empty.

In this example, it wouldn't be hard to change `unpack` to `((first xs) 0)` and `vector` to `((first xs) 1)`, but this quickly gets ugly if more work needs to be done on (first xs).

Is there any way to effectively use a let statement part-way through a cond?

Thanks.

-Nate

Comment: Hi - it is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve here. You might find this interesting http://www.assembla.com/spaces/clojure/tickets/200  and   http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/c1097ce07506fc39    Please consider stating what the function is supposed to do in your question, and some example inputs and outputs. The syntax does not look like a valid cond statement as the body of the cond is wrapped in a vector.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In cases like these, you're best off using `if-let`:

```
(defn operate-on-list [xs]
  (if-let [[unpack v] (first xs)]
    (cond
      unpack v
      :else  (operate-on-list (rest xs)))))
```

This code walks the given <strike>list</strike> seq-able (list, vector, array...) of vectors and returns the second element of the first vector whose first element is true (meaning not `false` or `nil`). `nil` is returned if no such vector is found.

Note that `vector` is a built-in function, so I've chosen `v` as the variable name, just in case the need to use the function in the body arises in the future. More importantly, you're using too many brackets in your cond syntax; fixed in this version.

**UPDATE**: Two additional things worth noting about `if-let`:

1. The way `if-let` works, if `(first xs)` happens to be `nil` (`false` would be the same), the destructuring binding never takes place, so Clojure won't complain about not being able to bind `nil` to `[unpack v]`.
2. Also, `if-let` accepts an else clause (in which you can't refer to the variables bound in `if-let` bindings vector -- though if you're in the else clause, you know they where `false` or `nil` anyway).

Comment: See also `when-let` which is more idiomatic when you have only one branch.

Comment: A second note: be aware that `if-let` works here, because the list is supposed to contain vectors. In general `(when-let [x (first s)] ...)` is *not* a substitute for `(when-let [s (seq s)] (let [f (first s)] ...))`.

Answer (score 3):

```
    ;use conditional let: http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/cond-api.html

    (use 'clojure.contrib.cond)

    (cond-let [b]  
      nil  b
      12  (prn (+ b 1))
      :else 17 )

    ;==> 13
```

Another good example can be found here  http://www.mail-archive.com/clojure@googlegroups.com/msg03684.html

Answer (score 2):

Sort of like this, with a `let` inside the scope of the `cond`?

```
(defn operate-on-list [list]
  (let [ el_first (first list) ]
    (cond
      (nil? el_first) (println "Finished")
      :else (do 
       (let [ list_rest (rest list) ]
                (println el_first)  
                (operate-on-list list_rest))))))

(operate-on-list '(1 2 3))
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
Finished
```

Comment: @Brian Carper: you're right; you can simply omit the do.  That was an Elisp hangover on my part (in particular, progn).